# Match an image to bucket of images using Amazon Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

I am using [Amazon Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/) in a project. My requirement is to upload a set of products to the bucket initially and when a user uploads an image to my portal he/she should get matching(similar) image/images from my bucket as a result. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Rekognition only supports a set of labels, Amazon keeps expanding it but they don't support user defined labels. Here is a snippet from their FAQ ([source](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/faqs/#object-and-scene-detection))

> **Q. I can’t find the label I need. How do I request a new label?**
>
> Please send us your requests through AWS Customer Support. Amazon
>   Rekognition continuously expands its catalog of labels based on
>   customer feedback.

---